# SQLAlchemy doesn't autoload all my columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an issue, where I use the following:

```
class Docs(Base):       
    __tablename__ = "docs"

    __table__ = Table(__tablename__, Base.metadata, 
        Column("dID", Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column("d_type", Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column("d_category", Integer, primary_key=True),
        autoload_with=get_global_db_engine())

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("dID", "d_type", "d_category"),)

    # Class Globals
    COLUMNS = __table__.columns.keys()
```

Problem is, when I loop through`COLUMNS` - it doesn't list *all* the columns of `__table__`, it holds only the columns I pre-defined inside the `Table` ( 3 cols ).

How do I get `COLUMNS` to return all of them ?

Comment: Also add `autoload=True` to the `Table(...)`

Comment: @van If `autoload_with` is set it implies that `autoload=True`, no need to set `autoload=True` explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set `extend_existing` to extend your defined table with reflected columns.

From the [documenation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.extend_existing):

> Table.extend_existing will also work in conjunction with Table.autoload to run a new reflection operation against the database, even if a Table of the same name is already present in the target MetaData; newly reflected Column objects and other options will be added into the state of the Table, potentially overwriting existing columns and options of the same name.

So,

```
__table__ = Table(__tablename__, Base.metadata, 
    Column("dID", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("d_type", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("d_category", Integer, primary_key=True),
    extend_existing=True,
    autoload_with=get_global_db_engine())
```

should do the trick.